# jQuery redirect to site base url with php code (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to redirect after a form submission to base url of a Wordpress website.

The problem is redirect looks something like this: 
http://current-url/%3C?php%20echo%20get_site_url();%20?%3E

Following is my code:

```
if (jQuery(".redirecting_content:visible").is(":visible") == true) {  
 setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.replace("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>");                           
 }, 4000); 
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (jQuery(".redirecting_content:visible").is(":visible") == true) {  
 var base_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/"
 setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.replace(base_url);                           
 }, 4000); 
};
```